# Google Cloud- New Disk while Creating VM-Redundancy Options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, regional

1. Referencing this as well:
   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk#repd_create_disk  
   It seems to imply that we cannot directly define the disk as having regional redundancy at time of creation of a VM(no such disk option visible). Only after creation of VM, we need to go to Storage Section and create disk with redundancy option and then attach it to VM.

[image: Image showing redundancy option under 'Storage' Section]

2.Additionally,with regard to Local SSDs [which are non persistent], looks like we cannot randomly attach them while a VM is running, seems like option below appears only at time of VM creation?:

[image: Local SSd option while creating new VM]

---

[image: Local SSD option not visible if we try editing existing VM]

Kind regards, 
Aditya

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article [1], regional persistent disk cannot be created as boot disk. And it need to be attached after the VM is created.

And for your second question, yes, you can add local SSD only during VM creation. According to this [2]:

"Local SSDs are located on the physical machine where your virtual machine instance is running, they can be created only during the instance creation process. Local SSDs cannot be used as boot devices"

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#create_local_ssd